# How to change bootstrap modal header colors (backgrond & text)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How could I change the bootstrap modal header background to dark-blue and the text to white. Fiddle is here :

https://www.bootply.com/kzdpQurfsl

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to use the following CSS:

```
.modal-header {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
}
```

[Fiddle is here](https://www.bootply.com/fQ8lUvrXDk).

Answer (score 3):

Rather than changing the colours of all the modals why not add this to an extension CSS file.

```
.modal-header.primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  border-color: #337ab7;
}
```

and then add primary to your modal-header thus:

```
<div class="modal-header primary">
```

[Fiddle is here...](https://www.bootply.com/nDipeRtZ7f)

Answer (score 0):

Override the modal-header css class:

```
.modal-header {
     color: white:
     background-color: blue;   // Code of the exact color you want
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
.modal-header{
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
}
```